# In theory, shouldn't there be multiple BAO peaks and even troughs?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, bao

Shouldn't acoustic oscillations created by primordial matter anisotropies create multiple peaks and troughs when those oscillations are frozen by decoupling ? It's not unthinkable to imagine that the exact calculations of the expected amplitudes of each will lead to a result where the first peak is much more significant than the rest, but do those other peaks and troughs theoretically exist, just at very small currently non measurable amplitudes ? In other words, the BAO peak corresponds to the first peak in the CMB power spectrum, but am I wrong in assuming the other peaks and troughs are theoretically also present in present matter distribution, just at negligible amplitude ?

As a bonus, if the answer is indeed yes, why are the other peaks so negligible ? I understand that the first one has the greatest amplitude, but why are the remaining ones so vanishingly small as to remain undetected in current matter distribution, despite being nowhere near insignificant in the CMB power spectrum ?